# replace footer graphic in all sections

Tags: vba, image, replace, ms-word, footer

My company is re-branding. The current footer graphic has to be replaced by the new one. I know there's a way with VBA to delete the old image and insert the new one, but I can't figure out how to do it. I need the new image to be behind the text, not inline. I also need it to be 8.1 wide x .21 high. Position is centered to page and -.05 below bottom margin. Can anyone help? Doing it all manually is driving me insane.

I tried recording a macro to see what my steps were, but I guess I can't right-click while recording? I tried recording it as an inline shape, but even then, the macro quit recording after I inserted the shape. so I can't see how to format it.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ReplaceLogo()
    Dim Shp, footerRng As Range, oSec As Section
    Const LOGO = "D:\temp\logo.png" ' modify as needed
    For Each oSec In ActiveDocument.Sections
        Set footerRng = oSec.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        ' Remove old logo
        ' modify as needed, if multiple images in footer
        For Each Shp In footerRng.InlineShapes
            Shp.Delete
        Next
        For Each Shp In footerRng.ShapeRange
            Shp.Delete
        Next
        Set Shp = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=LOGO, LinkToFile:=False, _
            SaveWithDocument:=True, Anchor:=footerRng)
        With Shp
            .Top = .Top - InchesToPoints(0.05)
            .Left = wdShapeCenter
            .Height = InchesToPoints(0.21)
            .Width = InchesToPoints(8.1)
            .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Shapes.AddPicture method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.shapes.addpicture?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm161415183)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [WrapFormat object (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wrapformat?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm2499)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: Oh, my lord, it works!!! And it's so much simpler than the other codes I had been trying. THANK YOU SO MUCH!! You have saved me untold hours of tedious work! I did add oSec.PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = True under the Set footerRng line to get it to do the odd and even pages. I just can't thank you enough. THANK YOU!!!!!!

Comment: Oops. Typo. I set oSec.PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False.

Comment: Ok, i guess I don't understand how to get the graphic on to both the odd and even pages. Its is only showing up on the odd pages with all page setup the same. But when I Need different odd and even pages, the header and footer only show up on the odd pages. So I am doing something wrong with the oSec.PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = True

Comment: If the code answered the question in your post, please mark is as an answer and create a new post for it. More detail is helpful for revising the code. [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)